# Best UI element for displaying results of XML parsing

Tags: iphone

i am a student and also new to iphone SDK.i want to do xml parsing which has image URL and Data,it is a XML file about news.i have to show it .can i use table view or navigation controller? which is the best way?i have to show images and titles in first page.when i click it,it shows other page to show full news with image. is there any tutorial for what i need?

Answer (score 2):

Table View and Navigation controllers are two entirely different things.  It's like asking whether you should use a hammer or a nail to hang something.  You could use both.  YOu could also use a screw and a screwdriver, or any number of other ways to hang something on the wall.

A Navigation controller allows you to move around in a view heirarchy. See the Apple Contacts app to see how you can move around.  Now, if you want to have a list of items, then you could use TableView to make a table of items.  You don't have to have a UITableView inside a Navigation controller view.  Or you may want to.

I would start at Apple's [Creating iPhone Apps](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/gettingstarted/docs/creatingiphoneapps.action), and then go look at the Stanford's online course, and [this one](http://icodeblog.com/2008/08/08/iphone-programming-tutorial-populating-uitableview-with-an-nsarray/), among countless others.

You have chosen to bite off quite a big chunk with your first project.

Comment: can i show image and also text in same row in navigation controller

Comment: @senthilmuthu do you actually know what a navigation controller is?
maybe you want to do some research before asking such a question.
The tutorials provided by mahboudz will help you with that.

Comment: @senthilmuthu I'd love to help you more, but you really should start at the very beginning.  Think of the Navigation Controller as a window on your PC.  It's got some buttons on it and some controls on the sides and some other buttons around.  Can you display images and text in rows in that Window?  Of course.  That window can do a lot of things.

Now, one way to put images and text, in rows, into a window is using UITableView.  So, in other words, you can put a UITableView inside a UINavigationController.  

But before you can walk, you should crawl.  Start with programming a simple view.